# Show that the set $\{1,2,\ldots, n-1\}$ is a group under $\bmod n$ IFF $n$ is prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I need to show that this set, together with the operation of multiplication mod $n$, is a group if, and only if, $n$ is prime.

What would be the best way to proceed? proof by contradiction? (i.e. letting $n$ be some non-prime, etc.)

Comment: If $n$ is not a prime then for any divisor $d$  of $n$ ( $d\neq1,n$) try to check if inverse exists.

Comment: @PVanchinathan I actually managed to find the inverse which is strange. 
Let n=10,
U(10)={1,3,7,9}
The inverse of 1 is 1, inverse of 3 is 7, inverse of 7 is 3 and inverse of 9 is 9.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but showing the claim does not hold for some particular $n$ e.g. $n=10$ is NOT enough. You seem to be fundamentally misunderstanding what IFF means and how proof by contradiction works. EDIT: Asker edited question; this comment no longer applies entirely.

Comment: Also, in response to your comment in response to @PVanchinathan, you did not do what he asked. He said to look for an inverse of a proper divisor of $n$. Can you find an inverse for $2$ or $5$? (I'll save you the trouble; you cannot.)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be struggling with the basic approach to proving if and only if type statements and understanding proof by contradiction. If you're not sure how to start, begin by breaking down the proof. Firstly, understand that the if and only if statement consists of two logically independent parts -  the if and the only if. Let's begin by proving the only if statement.

This says that "the set $\{1,2,...n-1\}$ is a group under$\mod n$ only if n is prime." This is much stronger than saying that for some particular non-prime $n$ the aforesaid set is not a group - what we are saying here is that it is not a group for all non-prime $n$.

This is quite easy to show. If $n$ is not prime, we can write $n=ab$, where $a,b$ in $\{2,...n-1\}$ are proper divisors of $n$. Could you use this to show that multiplication is not closed under$\mod n$?

Next, we come to the if part. This says that "the set $\{1,2,...n-1\}$ is a group under$\mod n$ if $n$ is prime." It is trivial to demonstrate that multiplication under$\mod n$ is associative and has identity $1$. Closure is also not too hard: the residue of $ab$ under$\mod n$ belongs to ${0,1,...n-1}$; can you see why it cannot be $0$ is $n$ is prime? The tricky part is showing that any element $a$ in $\{1,...n-1\}$ has an inverse. We use a non-constructive proof (i.e. the proof doesn't tell us what the $a^{-1}$ is, but we can be sure that it exists).

Consider the set $S=\{ax \pmod n|x\in \{1,...n-1\}\}$. By closure $S\subset \{1,...n-1\}$. How many distinct elements does $S$ have? Can you use this to show that $1\in S$? (If you do, then the $x$ by which a was multiplied to form $1$ is the required inverse).